# Testbench of floating point adder in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to write [floating point double precision adder](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html). in the test-bench of that, I have some problems.

*adder is a module which gets two 64bits number and  give sum of them.

this is my test bench:

```
module testadder;
  reg [63:0]           a;
  reg [63:0]           b;
  wire [63:0]          sum; 
  reg[10:0] expa,expb,expsum;
  reg signa,signb,signsum,one;
  reg[51:0] fa,fb,fsum;
  real ta,tb,fa2,fb2,sumcheck,fsum2,resultmodulesum;
  integer i;  
  reg [10:0]h23;

adder nameofinstance(sum,a,b);
initial begin  
   for(i=0;i<1000;i=i+1)
   begin
     h23=1023;
     one=1'b1;
   a = {$random(),$random()};
   b = {$random(),$random()};
   #10;
    expa=a[62:52]-h23;
    expb=b[62:52]-h23;
    fa=a[51:0];
    fb=b[51:0];
    signa=a[63];
    signb=b[63];
    fa2 = ( $bitstoreal(fa)/(2**52) )+ one ;
    ta=(-1)**(signa)*fa2*(2**expa);
    fb2 = ( $bitstoreal(fb)/(2**52) ) + one;
    tb=(-1)**(signb)*fb2*(2**expb);
    sumcheck=ta+tb;
    fsum=sum[51:0];
    signsum=sum[63];
    fsum2 = ( $bitstoreal(fsum)/(2**52) ) +one;
    expsum=$bitstoreal(sum[62:52])-1023;
    resultmodulesum=(-1)**(signsum)*fsum2*(2**expsum);
    if(sumcheck!=resultmodulesum)
      $display("wrong");


 end
end
endmodule




 module adder(sum,a, b);
    input [63:0]   a;
    input [63:0] b;
    reg [63:0] fa,fb;
    always @(a or b) begin
    fa={1'b1,a[51:0],12'b0};
    fb={1'b1,b[51:0],12'b0};
    end
    endmodule
```

1. when i add `( $bitstoreal(fa)/(2**52) )` with one , fa2 get 1 ! but when i don't add it , `fa2` get real value of `(fa/2^52)`.
   so I change my code to something like that to avoid adding with one, but another problem appears!

my change for making `ta`,`tb` and `resultmodulesum`:
(example for fa)

```
 fa2 = ( $bitstoreal(fa)/(2**52) ) ;
 ta=(-1)**(signa)*(fa2*(2**expa)+(2**expa));
```

2.then i understand that ta always get to `(-1)**(signa)*(2**expa)`;
it means that `fa2*(2**expa)` is 0 ! but i don't know why and what can I do to make it correct. 
I think that even if I didn't change my `fa2` and `fa2` (with one added in it) give correct output, my `ta` might has a problem.

3.I have another problem in my module that it is really strange!
little part of adder code module comes after test-bench code.
it is that when i debug my code, 63th bit of `fb` is 0! any idea?

Comment: What do you think `$bitstoreal` does? Have you checked this function in isolation, works as expected? If the module adder has nothing to do with the question can it be removed.

Comment: I expected that it converts binary numbers to real, and in the examples which i have seen it does that.am I wrong? question 3. is about module adder @morgan

Comment: I thought it was just for type conversion, allowing a real number be converted to 64 bits so it could be passed through a 64 bit port, using `$realtobits` and `$bitstoreal` my impression is that he bit in the middle exposes the bits of the floating point double as defined by IEEE 754. This will look like the correct number unless part of the exponent is set.

Comment: Could you explain more ?  I could not understand what you mean. I had said that it it conversion like your idea,i can't understand what you want to say in these sentences: "my impression is that he bit in the middle exposes the bits of the floating point double as defined by IEEE 754. This will look like the correct number unless part of the exponent is set."  what is wrong in my codes?@morgan

Comment: `$bitstoreal` turns a IEEE 754 double bit partern into a real number. `$realtobits` turns a real number into a IEEE 754 double bit pattern. In your code your use of these functions is not obvious to me. Your use of variable names does not make it clear what is an exponent and fraction [IEEE 754 double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer but more than can be expressed in the comments.

For the model of the floating point double I would have expected to see something along the lines of:

```
reg [63:0] a;
reg [63:0] b;

//Built in real for verification of code
real result;
real a_real;
real b_real;

initial begin
  a = {$random(),$random()};
  b = {$random(),$random()};

  #1ps;
  a_real = $bitstoreal(a);
  b_real = $bitstoreal(b);
  result = a_real + b_real;

  $display("a      %64b", a);
  $display("b      %64b", b);
  $display("a_real %f", a_real);
  $display("b_real %g", b_real);
  $display("result %f",  result);

  #1ps;
  $finish;
end
```

For splitting the randomised doubles up in to parts I would have expected to see some thing like:

```
wire a_sign;           // 1 bit
wire [10:0] a_exponent;//11 bit
wire [51:0] a_fraction;//52 bit

assign a_sign     = a[63]   ;
assign a_exponent = a[62:52];
assign a_fraction = a[51:0] ;

wire b_sign;           // 1 bit
wire [10:0] b_exponent;//11 bit
wire [51:0] b_fraction;//52 bit

assign b_sign     = b[63]   ;
assign b_exponent = b[62:52];
assign b_fraction = b[51:0] ;
```

Comment: Here I do some thing like your second code , but I want to calculate real number of these representation, so  the decimal value represented is:*(-1)^s  x f x 2^e where e = E - bias and f = ( F/(2^n) ) + 1, then I add these two decimal to and compare the answer with module answer to understand whether it is correct or not. (you can see the formula* in the link I have mentioned in my question) @morgan

Comment: h23 is bias here (in my code ) and n is 52, so i write this:`fa2 = ( $bitstoreal(fa)/(2**52) )+ one ;` fa2 is f and fa is F in previous comment . also `ta=(-1)**(signa)*fa2*(2**expa);` is the formula

Comment: I understand my problem morgan. it was about understanding $bitstoreal and $realtobits work. tnx